# UIGraphicsImageRenderer producing Larger file size for Smaller image?

Tags: swift

I am resizing an image and in doing so I find that the reduced image produces a larger file than the original. This for the same image.

```
func imageResizedForSMS() -> UIImage? {
    guard let image = self.image else {print("No image to resize");return nil}
    let maxDimension:CGFloat = 1280
    guard max(image.size.width,image.size.height) > maxDimension else {print("Original image within proper sizing");return image}

    let scaleRatio = min(image.size.width,image.size.height) / max(image.size.width,image.size.height)
    let scaledTarget = maxDimension * scaleRatio
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width >= image.size.height ? maxDimension : scaledTarget, height: image.size.height >= image.size.width ? maxDimension : scaledTarget)
    
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
    let scaledImage = renderer.image { _ in
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
    }
    
    let imageData = scaledImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    let imageSize = imageData?.count ?? 0
    print("Size of resized image = \(Double(imageSize) / 1000.0) KB")
    
    let imageData2 = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    let imageSize2 = imageData2?.count ?? 0
    print("Size of original image = \(Double(imageSize2) / 1000.0) KB")
    
    return scaledImage
}
```

The original image dimensions are `4032X3024` and the resized dimensions are `1280X960`. However, the resized file size is `11733.6 KB` while the original file size is `7088.8 KB`

From the debugger log:

```
Size of resized image = 11733.636 KB

Size of original image = 7088.865 KB

Printing description of image:
<UIImage:0x283978b40 anonymous {4032, 3024} renderingMode=automatic>
Printing description of scaledImage:
<UIImage:0x28394d320 anonymous {1280, 960} renderingMode=automatic>
```

How is that a reduction in image dimensions is producing a much larger file size?

Answer (score 0):

As usual I figure it out shortly after posting the question no matter how much time was spent prior to posting....

The issue appears to be the display scale. If I set a trait with a displayScale of 1 and then use the code above, the file size is indeed much reduced. It drops from the previous `11733KB` to `1474KB` which is much smaller than the original of `7088KB`

The updated portion of the code above that fixes this issue:

```
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat(for: UITraitCollection(displayScale: 1))
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize, format: format)
    let scaledImage = renderer.image { _ in
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
    }
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, it makes the image size smaller, but the quality of the image is also reduced. Did you find any solution to maintain the original quality of the image?